# unable to locate libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386 on ubuntu14.04.3 [don't starve server]

Tags: server, apt

And i need it for a don't starve server

```
apt-get update && apt-get  install   libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages          
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you are unable to locate the package, but you could download it from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libcurl4-gnutls-dev) and install it manually.
Go to the location of the downloaded file and type:

> dpkg -i libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5_i386.deb

Answer (score -1):

I had to install the i386 architecture.

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

then update apt and try the install again

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386

APM